# How to import/export iPhone addressbook on Linux?

Tags: linux, iphone, import, export, address-book

Is there any way, and if yes - how, to export addressbook from iphone to Linux, and then import it back (after some modification)? The iphone in question is not jailbroken, and this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I can think of to do it, off the top of my head: sync your iPhone address book to Google, download file from Google to Linux box, edit at your leisure, import back into Google, sync to iPhone.

Comment: But how can I sync iphone to google on linux?

Comment: @depesz iPhone to Google sync will need to be done by creating an Exchange account on your iPhone http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252

Comment: Great. It worked.